# Objects in Javascript / Phonegap undefined

Tags: javascript, object, cordova

My Code looks like this:

```
var app = {
    info: {
        one: "1",
        two: "abc",
        three: "cba",
        four: "abcd",
        objOne: {
            one: 1201, 
            two: 52,
            three: 941,
            four: "message"
        },
        objTwo: {
            one: "50.07995",
            two: "8.248324"
        }
        }
    }
```

When I try to access the variables via `app.info.objOne.one` i get `'undefined'`.

I really don't know why I cant get the properties of the objects and I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: To be more specific this code works fine in any Browser tested, the Problem occurs when parsing the Code to a Phonegap App under Android.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are forgot to insert closing curly `}`brace at end of the code.

This one is working fine.

```
var app = {
    info: {
        one: "1",
        two: "abc",
        three: "cba",
        four: "abcd",
        objOne: {
            one: 1201, 
            two: 52,
            three: 941,
            four: "message"
        },
        objTwo: {
            one: "50.07995",
            two: "8.248324"
        }

    }
 } //you forgot this one

 alert(app.info.objOne.one);
```

Comment: I got that Bracket in my code above, but thank you for trying.